# In Javascript (not JQuery), how do I make the window close after 2 seconds?

Tags: javascript

How do I create a function that will close the window after 2 seconds?

```
<a href="" onclick="close_it(); return false;">
    Click to close the window after 2 seconds
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `setTimeout` where an action is postponed for x number of milliseconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  window.close();
}, 2000);
```